# Getting null data on storing GET request array object response in jmeter

Tags: arrays, jmeter, response, store, beanshell

I am getting null data while storing GET request response, Response that I am getting is in the form of array object sample response as follows

I have used JSON Extractor to extract the data
`Name of the created variable = userList JSON Path expressions: stringfy(jsonData.data)`
<kbd>Note:- also used $.stringfy(jsonData.data) or $.jsonData.data</kbd>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IluMa.png)

also I have used BEANSHELL POST Processor to extract the request with the following script
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI8nO.png)

Expecting to store the array object response, such that I can pass that response to other POST request body

Comment: Could you provide the response? and what you want to store in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

`stringfy(jsonData.data)` is not a valid [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression

It's hard to say how exactly you need to modify it without seeing your response data and knowing what exactly you need to extract from there.

You can try using [deep scan](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) operator, something like:

```
$..data
```

and it will return all `data` attribute values no matter where they're placed in your JSON response.

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

If it's not giving what you need you can consider [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) or [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with Groovy language as:

1. [Groovy has built-in JSON parsing/creating capabilities](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
2. It's [recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) since JMeter 3.1